# Copy outbound data of Serial to Serial1 for Pro Micro

Tags: serial, softwareserial, arduino-leonardo, arduino-pro-micro

I am working on a bluetooth HID device. There are libraries which make HID devices a cake walk if you are making a wired version of your HID device.
I managed to configure my bluetooth module to appear as a HID device to the system, it however does nothing yet.
I figured if I route the serial data, that my wired version of device is sending to the system on Serial, to Serial1 my bluetooth device will function the same way the wired device worked.

If I am not wrong, code that I came across, maps RX of Serial to TX of Serial1.

```
Void setup(){ 
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
     if(Serial.available()){   
      char get= Serial.read();
      Serial1.Write(get);
     }
}
```

What I want to do is map the TX pin of Serial to TX pin of Serial1 of the pro micro.

Comment: What is your actual question?  As I understood, you want to forward the data, that you receive on Serial to the Serial1 interface. That's exactly what your code does (except for the spelling error with the big W in `Serial1.Write(get)`).

Comment: Re “_map the TX pin of Serial to TX pin of Serial1_”: you are rather forwarding from `Serial`’s **RX** to `Serial1`’s TX.

Comment: @chrisl I don't want to forward the data that I receive on Serial, I want to forward the data that Serial is sending to the system.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I want to forward TX of Serial to TX of Serial1. Is there a way to do that? Maybe there's a register where data is stored before writing it on the Serial?

Comment: Maybe the context is missing in your question. When you want to send the same data to Serial and Serial1, just always use `Serial.write()` and `Serial1.write()` together with the same data. Or is there any reason, why you cannot do this?

Comment: @chrisl I am using the ArduinoJoystick library by MHeironimus. Whatever communication it does over the Serial connection is done underneath. I went through it's code but couldn't find anything similar to Serial.begin(). It does however use the `DynamicHID` library which in turn uses the `PluggableUSB` library. I don't have an electronics background so I couldn't understand much there.

Comment: Thats because the ArduinoJoystick library does not use Serial. It configures the micro to act as HID-USB device. That is completely different to Serial communication. Thus you cannot just send that over a Serial interface

Comment: What bluetooth device do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113370/discussion-between-chrisl-and-revolution).